# varargin varargout function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a simple task to do in MATLAB using `varargin`/`out` for matrices.

I have to return result of multiplication elements with the same row and column number like so:

[image: like this]

`tab(1,1) * tab(2,2)` and so on.

I wrote some code but it only returns result for first matrix. The multiplication works because I checked using `disp(result)` after multiplication.

Here is my code, how should I change it to return results of all matrices?

```
function varargout = test(varargin)

n = length(varargin);
disp(n); 
for k=1:n
    [row, col] = size(varargin{k});
    result = 1;
    for i=1:row
        for j=1:col
            if i == j
            result = result * varargin{k}(i,i);
            end
        end
    varargout{k} = result;
    end
end
```

Comment: nothing to do with your question but if you want to multiply the diagonal elements your can use: `prod(diag(M))`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but your function can be re-written as one line:

```
function varargout = test2(varargin) 

    varargout = cellfun(@(x) prod(diag(x)), ...
                        varargin,...
                        'UniformOutput', false);

end
```

You can (initially) use this as a function to validate your own function, and (later) learn a lot from it by figuring out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The number of arguments returned will be defined by how you call the function.  For example, if you wrote:

```
a = test(x, y, z);
```

only the first output argument would be returned.  In contrast,

```
[a, b] = test(x,y,z);
```

would return the first and second outputs.  If you want to just return a cell array with the results, name your output argument something other than `varargout` and you will end up with a single output, with the results of each input in a cell.

Comment: I add r1 = (ones(1,n)); before first loop and r1(1,i) = result; instead of varargout{k} = result; and now I have 4 output arguments even tho i created 1x3 array.

Comment: Your iteration index for the size of inputs is `k`, so you probably don't want to use `i` when you are assigning to your output variable...